# How to check if a view was added dynamically or via xml

Tags: java, android

The title says it.

Example (my case): I have a RelativeLayout inside a ScrollView. the RelativeLayout has some views added in xml and I'm also adding views to it by clicking in a button. I want to scroll to the dynamically added view that is closer to the top.

```
mScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, ???.getTop());
```

Comment: When you create the `View` dynamically, just keep a reference to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add some flag to views you add manually. For example, you can use setTag() method.
Or you can save how many items there were in relativeLayout before you start adding items.